# Easy way to do ajax uploading with paperclip in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file, upload, paperclip

I was wondering if there was an easy way e.g. a plugin, to do ajax uploading in rails with paperclip or am I going to have to build it from scratch?

Cheers!

Edit: Also, I'm looking for a non-flash solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I think the answer to this is no. I went with the good old iframe faux-ajax upload, I think we're stuck with this until all the browser support the nice new html uploading.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `remotipart`(http://os.alfajango.com/remotipart). It's a gem fine integrated with Rails 3.1 and 3.0.

I have tried it, and all the ajax-file-upload handled like magic.

Comment: The project using iframe to make the upload ajax-like. But you don't have to actually deal with it. Look at the form part of it here https://github.com/JangoSteve/Rails-jQuery-Demo/blob/remotipart/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You'll find two versions of ajax upload on https://github.com/apneadiving/Pic-upload---Crop-in-Ajax.

Branch `master`: it uses http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Branch `uploadify`: It uses Uploadify: http://www.uploadify.com/

Both have built-in Crop.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.

Perhaps my solution is your solution

[Problem paperclip with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886708/problem-paperclip-with-ajax)