# Problem paperclip with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, paperclip

I am reading this tutorial : http://sleekd.com/general/adding-multiple-images-to-a-rails-model-with-paperclip/
 because i need Save the product images in a independent model. However when Product.create execute don´t save the data for product images model.

NOTE: I use the new pack action because i need to use ajax for create a new product.

Please I need Help.

My Code

Controllers

```
    class Admin::PacksController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @pack = Pack.new
        @product = Product.new
        4.times {@product.product_images.build} # added this
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @pack }
        end
      end

      def create_starred_product
        product = Product.new(params[:product])
        product.save
...

      end
```

View

```
<% form_remote_for @product, :url => {:controller => "products", :action => "create_starred_product"}, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
      <div id="content">
....#OTHER FIELDS OF PRODUCT. ITS SAVE METHOD IS OK
        <div id="images-selector">
          <span class="fleft">Imágenes</span><br/>
          <% count = 0 %>
          <% f.fields_for :product_images do |builder| %>

              <% if builder.object.new_record? %>
                  <label>
                    Imagen <%= "#{count = count + 1}" %>
                  </label>
                  <%= builder.file_field :photo, :class => "textarea" -%><br/>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <p><%= f.submit "Crear" %></p>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

Models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :packs, :through => :pack_products
  has_many :product_images, :dependent => :destroy
  #PAPERCLIP
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['product_image'].blank? }
end

class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_attached_file :photo, :url => "/:attachment/:class/:id/:style_:basename.:extension", :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>", :small => "30x30>" }
end
```

Comment: Excuse me I had a error in the title.I did not realize. The question is about of paperclip and Ajax. Now I read that paperclip and ajax don´t work together (javascript security model) so I need a alternative solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't upload files using AJAX, just like you said. There are, however, alternate solutions.

The common technique to accomplish this is the usage of an iframe. Have a look [here](http://khamsouk.souvanlasy.com/articles/ajax-file-uploads-in-rails-using-attachment_fu-and-responds_to_parent), this tutorial is oriented towards attachment_fu but it'll work with paperclip as well. [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is worth checking out and can also be used with paperclip on [rails 2.3](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/07/21/uploadify-and-rails23/) and [rails 3](https://github.com/websymphony/Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify).

Comment: I could to do that form send multipart information through jQuery Form plugin. Now I could not save. Why?. My model is bas or controller. I need save the images how paperclip plugin.

Comment: You couldn't save because the image wasn't sent correctly because of what I said. Did you explore the links I left? If not, give them a look.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution together with my partner.

My error was in nested attributes form, no in Ajax.so I found the solution for to use paperclip with Ajax. Now I posted example code.

However I explain the code.

Models

Two models

Product and Product_images

I wanted that when i created a product in ajax form (each product belongs_to pack).
Each product has many images in product_images model. Therefore I wanted save images too.

The code

Controller Ajax action

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
      def create_starred_product
        product = Product.new(params[:product])
        product.save

        render :update do |page|
          page.replace_html 'star-product', :partial => "admin/products/star_product_name", :locals => {:star_product => product}
          page.call "$j.modal.close"
        end
end

  end
```

Models

Products model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :packs, :through => :pack_products
  has_many :product_images, :dependent => :destroy

  #PAPERCLIP
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images#, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['product_image'].blank? }

  has_attached_file :photo, :url => "/:attachment/:class/:id/:style_:basename.:extension", :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>", :small => "30x30>" }
```

Product_images model

```
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  has_attached_file :photo, :url => "/:attachment/:class/:id/:style_:basename.:extension", :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>", :small => "30x30>" }
end  

end
```

View popup in ajax (These is a partial)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j('#product_submit').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $j('#uploadForm').ajaxSubmit({
                beforeSubmit: function(a, f, o) {
                    o.dataType = 'json';
                },
                complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                    // XMLHttpRequest.responseText will contain the URL of the uploaded image.
                    // Put it in an image element you create, or do with it what you will.
                    // For example, if you have an image elemtn with id "my_image", then
                    //  $('#my_image').attr('src', XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    // Will set that image tag to display the uploaded image.
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="new-starred-product" class="popup clearfix">
    <div id="header">Nuevo producto estrella</div>
  <% remote_form_for @product, :url => {:controller => "products", :action => "create_starred_product"}, :html => {:method => :post, :id => 'uploadForm', :multipart => true} do |f| %>
      <div id="content">
        <label>Nombre:</label> <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "textarea" %>
        <br/>
        <label>Precio:</label> <%= f.text_field :price, :class => "textarea" %>
        <br/>
        <%#= f.file_field :photo %>
        <div id="images-selector">

          <% count = 0 %>
          <%# f.fields_for "product_images_attributes[]", ProductImage.new do |builder| %>
          <% f.fields_for :product_images, 4.times {ProductImage.new} do |builder| %>
              <% if builder.object.new_record? %>
                  <label>
                    Imagen <%= "#{count = count + 1}" %>
                  </label>
                  <%= builder.file_field :photo, :class => "file-upload" -%><br />
                  <br/>
              <% end %>              
              <%#= builder.text_field :testfield %>
<!--ACA VA EL CODIGO PARA IMAGENES-->
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <label>Descripción</label><%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 10, :class => "textarea clearfix" -%>
        <br/>

        <p>
          <%#= f.submit "Crear" %>
        <%= link_to "Crear", "#", :id => "product_submit" %>
        </p>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I am using jquery and jquery-form plugin (search in google)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find two versions of ajax upload on https://github.com/apneadiving/Pic-upload---Crop-in-Ajax.

Branch `master`: it uses http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Branch `uploadify`: It uses Uploadify: http://www.uploadify.com/

Both have built-in Crop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem Was nested attributes form.later I posted the code

Answer (score 0):

Another gem to help with this issue I've just found when I've had the same problem is [remotipart](https://github.com/leppert/remotipart) - Highly recommended.